Cómo soluciono este error
import sqlite3

miConexion=sqlite3.connect("PrimeraBase")

miCursor=miConexion.cursor()

miCursor.execute("CREATE TABLE PRODUCTOS (NOMBRE_ARTICULO VARCHAR(50), PRECIO INTEGER, SECCION VARCHAR(20))")


File "D:\PYTHON\basedatos1.py", line 7, in 
miCursor.execute("CREATE TABLE PRODUCTOS (NOMBRE_ARTICULO VARCHAR(50), PRECIO INTEGER, SECCION VARCHAR(20))")
sqlite3.OperationalError: table PRODUCTOS already exists [Finished in
1.6s with exit code 1]


En el error dice: table PRODUCTOS already exists, la traducción en español es: La tabla PRODUCTOS ya existe. Si quieres ser desarrollador practica mucho inglés, ya que hay documentación especializada solo la consigues en ese idioma. Una solución es abrir el archivo de base de datos PrimeraBase con algún editor SQLite y borrar la tabla. La otra, más sencilla, es borrar totalmente el archivo PrimeraBase.

Como te hizo notar aeportugal, el error es que la tabla ya existe. Por lo tanto la solución pasa por crear otra tabla o verificar que la tabla no exista antes de crearla. Sería mejor que preguntes cómo hacerlo

Como el error claramente indica, el problema es que la tabla ya existe en la base de datos cuando intentas crearla.
Cada vez que ejecutes tu script y se ejecute esa query se intentará crear la tabla de nuevo y ésto no es posible si ya existe una tabla con el mismo nombre en la BD. Tienes varias opciones:

Eliminar la tabla si exite (DROP TABLE con cláusula IF EXISTS) y recrearla:
miCursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PRODUCTOS")
miCursor.execute("CREATE TABLE PRODUCTOS (NOMBRE_ARTICULO VARCHAR(50), PRECIO INTEGER, SECCION VARCHAR(20))")

Esto implica la pérdida de la toda la información almacenada en la tabla previamente de forma irreversible

Crear la tabla solo si no existe (opción IF NOT EXISTS de CREATE TABLE):
miCursor.execute("CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS PRODUCTOS (NOMBRE_ARTICULO VARCHAR(50), PRECIO INTEGER, SECCION VARCHAR(20))")



Obviamente también puedes eliminar por completo la base de datos, que no es más que un archivo, o condicionar la ejecución de las consultas encargadas de crear las tablas de forma que solo se ejecuten si la base de datos no existía previamente a la ejecución del script.
